# Aspect deactivates Spring Controller Mapping

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I created a Spring website.
I used an abstract generic controller class, with different implementations.
It works well if I don't activate the Aspect class on any Controllers.

If I activate an Aspect, then all Mappings seem to be deactivated:

> DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/contact/2]
>   WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found forHTTP request with URI [/clubhelperbackend/contact/2] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

This is my abstract controller:

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T extends Data> implements ClubController<T> {

protected Dao<T> dao;
private Class<T> elementClass;

public AbstractController(Dao<T> dao, Class<T> element) {
    super();
    this.dao = dao;
    this.elementClass = element;
}

@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAsView(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam(required = false) boolean ajax, Model m) {
    String mapping = elementClass.getSimpleName();
    m.addAttribute(mapping, getById(id));
    return mapping + "Get" + (ajax ? "Ajax" : "");
}

@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "application/json")
public T delete(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    T obj = getById(id);
    // dao.delete(id);
    return obj;
}
}
```

And an implementation:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController extends AbstractController<Contact> {

    @Autowired
    public ContactController(Dao<Contact> contactDao) {
        super(contactDao, Contact.class);
    }

}
```

This is my Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DeletedStorageAspect {
    //
    // private DeletedEntriesDao deletedEntriesDao;
    //
    // @Autowired
    // public DeletedStorageAspect(DeletedEntriesDao deletedEntriesDao) {
    // super();
    // this.deletedEntriesDao = deletedEntriesDao;
    // }

    @Pointcut("execution (public * de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.controller.abstr.AbstractController.delete(..))")
    private void invocation() {
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "invocation()", returning = "deleted")
    public void storeDeleted(JoinPoint joinPoint, Data deleted) {
        System.out.println("Deleted: " + deleted);
        String tableName = deleted.getClass().getSimpleName();
        long id = deleted.getId();
        Date now = new Date();
        DeletedEntries entry = new DeletedEntries(-1L, tableName, id, now, now);
        System.out.println(entry);
        // deletedEntriesDao.insert(entry);
    }
}
```

This is part of my beans.xml:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="mysqlDbCheckAspect" />
    <aop:include name="daoLoggerAspect" />
    <aop:include name="controllerSecurityAspect" />
    <aop:include name="deletedStorageAspect" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

I can restore full functionality by commenting deletedStorageAspect.

What causes this behaviour? Why are the mappings not recognized with an aspect on them? Are aspects not allowed on Controllers?

Hoping for some help, please.

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-proxying . In short add `proxy-target-class=true` to the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`.

Comment: @M.Deinum: That was it! Thank you. I don't quite understand what it does. If you explain in an answer I accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using AOP with Spring by default spring creates proxies. Depending on the fact if you implement interfaces on your class (or not) it will create a JDK Dynamic proxy (interface based) or CGLIB based proxy (class based).

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T extends Data> implements ClubController<T> {
```

In the case of an interface based proxy (which applies to you) the MVC infrastructure isn't able to see the `@RequestMapping` annotations anymore and will not detect your mappings anymore. This is also the case that applies to you as you are implementing an interface. Also see [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-proxying) on the matter of proxying with request mappings.

To fix it you must force the use of class based proxies, to do so add `proxy-target-class="true"` to the `<aop:aspectj-auto-proxy />`.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that removing the interface should also work?

Comment: In theory that should work as then a class based proxy should be created.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a AOP expert.But by looking at your code I can say Abstract class in not executing and that may be the root cause. So have to modify Pointcut execution expression.

### Solution 1

If you are not using delete signature for child classes you can easlily move to bello like abstract expression. It say's only within package like thing.

```
@Pointcut("execution (public * de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.controller.*.*.delete(..))")
private void invocation() {
}
```

### Solution 2

You can use logic gates for expression like this

```
@Pointcut("target(de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.controller.abstr.AbstractController)")
private void anyAbstractOperation() {}

@Pointcut("execution(public * *.delete(..))")
private void anyDeleteOperation() {}


@Pointcut("anyAbstractOperation() && anyDeleteOperation()")
private void invocation() {}
```

reference :
1.http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-combining

2.http://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-pointcut-tutorial

3.http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj

Explanation

About **this and target**

**this** limits matching to join points where the bean reference is an instance of the given type, while **target** limits matching to join points where the target object is an instance of the given type. The former works when Spring AOP creates a CGLIB-based proxy, and the latter is used when a JDK-based proxy is created. Suppose that the target class implements an interface:

```
public class FooDao implements BarDao {
    ...
}
```

In this case, Spring AOP will use the JDK-based proxy and you should use the target PCD because the proxied object will be an instance of Proxy class and implement the BarDao interface:

```
@Pointcut("target(org.baeldung.dao.BarDao)")
```

On the other hand if FooDao doesn’t implement any interface or proxyTargetClass property is set to true then the proxied object will be a subclass of FooDao and the this PCD could be used:

```
@Pointcut("this(org.baeldung.dao.FooDao)")
```

Comment: If I remove the Component Annotation, no Aspect is triggered (or even instanciated?). I tried with Aspects that work on other classes.